# Where should I ask a "question" about password security?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, login, security

So, I got blasted for asking for help with a security question I had (got my rep cut in half!) and I'm wondering where I should ask it... (granted my rep was only 40...)

---

Basically I know very little about passwords and hacking and i'm trying to learn.  My goal is to protect a webpage from casual to slightly determined users.  Basically I want you to have to do some work to get in.

So, I created a **very basic** page to demonstrate 4 different attempts at password protection.

http://dck.dx.am/locktest/locktest.html

The first would only really keep out people who know nothing of computers and webprogramming in general. (point of fact, this is where most of the people who blasted me stopped, and spontaneously lost all common decency/sense).

The other 3 go a little farther and I tried doing 'server-side authentication'.

The second is basically a copy of the first, except on the server.

The third stores the password in a txt file that PHP reads in.

The fourth stores a hashed copy of the password in the above mentioned txt file.

---

So, back to the question at hand, Is there a place for something like this?  To be clear, i'm not trying to learn how to Hack/crack passwords, but how to prevent that.

Comment: I think you will find this interesting: [The definite guide to form-based website authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) would be the best place for questions about password security.

However, questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21186074/1288) probably won't be well-received on any site in the Stack Exchange network.  Don't post a link and ask people to visit your site to get part of the question.

> Which of the (4) FOUR different methods are viable and/or the best method?

You should have explained the four methods in your question, not on another site.  Questions here should be able to stand alone. (*Especially* security questions. People are paranoid about security and they should be.)

Comment: Thank you for giving a constructive response!  I think I'll try again keeping that in mind.